# Load a javascript array using c# into a C# DataTable

Tags: javascript, c#

I need to read a javascript array from a .js file. The .js file has comments "//..." as well. Here's what the file looks like :

```
var myarraydata = [ 
{
    col1: "value1", 
    col2: "value2", 
    col3: "value3"
},
{
    col1: "x1", 
    col2: "x2", 
    col3: "x3"
}];
```

In the C#  windows application. A DataTable? with

```
columns : col1    col2    col3
Values  : value1  value2  value3
          x1      x2      x3
```

....Something like

```
File.ReadAllText(....
//Parse the data
```

Comment: what have you try to do?

Comment: @Liam JSON and JavaScript are **not the same thing**. That is not a valid JSON file.

Comment: Yup, its a js array :) being loaded via a .js file

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript arrays are representable with `JSON` objects. So you may could serialize and deserialize them using `Newtonsoft.Json`. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Just take a look at: [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

**EDIT**

Newtonsoft.Json is release under the **MIT** license. So you should be able to embed the source code directly, if needed. But in your case i would use the assembly, because updating to a newer version will be much easier.

Comment: thank you. Any points at not having to do this without including additional libraries?

Comment: Write your own JSON serialization. But you might download the sources of it and embed it into yours, if the licenses allows this. But the library is very lightweight and excellent to use.

Comment: Tx. I think I'll do some string parsing directly in c# and split the values using a basic regex. May be clunky but should avoid a bit of code. Thought someone may have a better approach than my initial thoughts. Some model view scenario etc...:)

Answer (score 0):

If anyones interested, I got this working using the standard .net classes :)

> [Microsoft Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here's sample code from the website :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace ExampleApplication
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var RegisteredUsers = new List<Person>();
            RegisteredUsers.Add(new Person() { PersonID = 1, Name = "Bryon Hetrick", Registered = true });
            RegisteredUsers.Add(new Person() { PersonID = 2, Name = "Nicole Wilcox", Registered = true });
            RegisteredUsers.Add(new Person() { PersonID = 3, Name = "Adrian Martinson", Registered = false });
            RegisteredUsers.Add(new Person() { PersonID = 4, Name = "Nora Osborn", Registered = false });

            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(RegisteredUsers);
            // Produces string value of:
            // [
            //     {"PersonID":1,"Name":"Bryon Hetrick","Registered":true},
            //     {"PersonID":2,"Name":"Nicole Wilcox","Registered":true},
            //     {"PersonID":3,"Name":"Adrian Martinson","Registered":false},
            //     {"PersonID":4,"Name":"Nora Osborn","Registered":false}
            // ]

            var deserializedResult = serializer.Deserialize<List<Person>>(serializedResult);
            // Produces List with 4 Person objects
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you MS